# Real device emulators on Nokia site

Tags: nokia

I remember a service where u could rent a phone online somewhere at Nokia site for testing, does this still exist?

Answer (score 1):

Yes http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/

Comment: @ lennie: this is right answer for ur question. You need to reserve it before you can start.